# GradlePropertiesModel(V2)

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, navigation

A build operation failed.
Cannot get GradlePropertiesModel (V2) for project 'GradleProject{path=':app'}'
Cannot get GradlePropertiesModel (V2) for project 'GradleProject{path=':app'}'

In my project, after uploading the necessary libraries to gradle in a compatible way, I constantly encounter this error during the build process. How can I solve it?

Comment: I too struggle with this after a recent update from Android Studio.  A hot fix is, invalidate cache and restart the android studio. make sure you open from "exact path" and do not open from "Recent project". May be this will helpful for now atleast..

Comment: If not works , try above steps along with deleting .idea and .gradle folder in the project.

Answer (score 0):

A method for troubleshooting and analysis:

When this error occurs, it is not directly presented in Android Studio. It merely provides a stack trace and highlights the GradlePropertiesModel (V2).
It is necessary to open detailed logs (there may be a direct link in the Build window in Android Studio).

For instance, in my case, I located the logs at:
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudioPreview2023.2\log
Open the idea.log file and analyze it carefully:

2024-01-04 16:55:53,864 [  11853]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.common.GradleInitScripts - Failed to create init script that applies the Android Studio Tooling plugin.
java.io.IOException: Unable to create a temporary file C:\Windows\Temp\sync.studio.tooling5.gradle
Directory 'C:\Windows\Temp' list (0 children): null
at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtilRt.doCreateTempFile(FileUtilRt.java:525)

So I clicked into C:\Windows\Temp and found that a regular click on the Temp directory doesn't allow access!!
A confirmation dialog is required. After confirming, there were no more prompts upon entering and exiting.
At this point, returning to Android Studio and resyncing resolved the issue.

This is indeed a strange issue, lacking permissions for the C:\Windows\Temp directory.